# How do i create a GNU Autotool Project in Eclipse CDT from existing C++ source code?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, development-environment, eclipse-cdt

I have an existing C++ source code that is built using autotools and i wish to use in Eclipse CDT. I'm a beginner with Eclipse CDT. I've installed the Autotools plugin for eclipse but don't know how to create a project from existing code.

May you please guide me in the right direction so that i can create an eclipse project that uses autotools to build this source code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to generate all makefiles and then try to import project to eclipse. I think when all Makefiles will exist, then would be no need to install any external plugin for autotools in eclipse IDE. It should work as it is.

Comment: There is also an autotools integration.  I think the correct answer would contain information on how to use that.